# Как реализовать поиск слова в html файле?

Tags: html, android

Подскажите, как реализовать поиск заданного слова на html странице?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String content = null;
URLConnection connection = null;
try {
  connection =  new URL("http://www.google.com").openConnection();
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(connection.getInputStream());
  scanner.useDelimiter("\\Z");
  content = scanner.next();
}catch ( Exception ex ) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}

if(content.indexOf("ИСКОМОЕ СЛОВО")!=-1)
    System.out.println("Искомое слово найдено!");
else
    System.out.println("Искомое слово НЕ найдено!");
```

**Обновление**

В таком случае надо заменить

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(connection.getInputStream());
```

на

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(connection.getInputStream(), "cp1251");
```

Comment: тут такое дело на сайте используется кодировка windows-1251, а код ищет в utf-8 вроде.